# GitHub Actions - Best Way to Reuse Secrets for Multiple Repositories

Tags: github-actions, github-enterprise, github-secret

GitHub Enterprise with thousands of repos in the organization.
My team has (currently) 15 repos and all need the same secrets.
Is there a way to "centralize" these secrets so I won't have to create/update these secrets in each repo individually?
Organization secrets are out of the question, I need something in the team/project scope

Answer (score 1):

You can set an organisation repo and then scope the secret to one or more repositories.

[image: scope the repo to select repositories]

Pick the repos you need

[image]

There is no other option in GitHub.

You could also setup an Azure Key Vault or similar and run a script to read the secrets and set them as a secret for the action job.

Answer (score 1):

You can add organisation secretes from cli.

```
# gh secret set name --org organization --repos "repository1,repository2,..."
```

Also, set an organization secret with a specific visibility.

```
# gh secret set name --org organization --visibility [all|private|selected]
```

For your reference,
[Github Organization Secretes](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/gh-secret-set-create-or-update-github-secrets-from-the-command-line/)